# How to get Respons time From Proses Vb Net in single click

Tags: vb.net

I want to get response time on a simple math value
if "button calculate" press, get sum value a and value b in textbox and also show how long to proceed that math calculation (response time) in textbox.

[image]

coding button calculate

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Timer1.Start()
    Me.stopwatch.Start()
    TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Count + 1 & " " & Label1.Text)

End Sub
```

"textbox4.text (to show the how long calculate proceed in ms)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim sw = New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
sw.Start()

Timer1.Start()
Me.stopwatch.Start()
TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text)
ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Count + 1 & " " & Label1.Text)

sw.[Stop]()
' time is a timespan that represents the time passed between sw.Start() and sw.Stop().
textbox4.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()
```

Comment: when i click calculate, nothing show in textbox4 like in picture,

Comment: If i have a lot of proceed it's also output 1 ms ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @DindaAmalia just to clarify you have put the code to stop the `Stopwatch` on the `Stop` button handler haven't you? It's unclear really what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @ZoharPeled why the result always up when i clicked continuous ?

-121 ms
-145 ms
-155 ms
and up

how to make it stable and less volatile ?

Comment: @zoharpeled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817694/time-elapsed-or-response-time-results-always-up-grow-up-make-it-stable