# Time Elapsed or Response Time Results always Up / Grow Up make it stable

Tags: vb.net, timer, stopwatch, elapsedtime

in Posting Before :
I want to get response time on a simple math value
if "button calculate" press, get sum value a and value b in textbox and also show how long to proceed that math calculation (response time) in textbox.

BUT why my result always grow up / always up like in picture
how to make result stable and less volatile ?

the result when i click calculate button on a continuous

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H9Fl.jpg)

coding button calculate

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim sw = New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()

    Timer1.Start()
    Me.stopwatch.Start()
    TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox4.Text)

    sw.Stop()
    ' time is a timespan that represents the time passed between sw.Start() and sw.Stop().
    TextBox4.Text = (sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString())
    sw.Reset() End Sub
```

Comment: Its not at all clear what you are asking.  "response time" usually refers to how long a person responds.  The only thing your stopwatch is timing is how long your code takes to execute 5 lines of code.

Comment: Your Stopwatch, "sw", is only measuring how long it takes to execute that code.  It's not taking into account any kind of user activity/response time.  I suspect the root of your problem lies elsewhere...likely in the Tick() event of that Timer?

Comment: @plutonix respon time mean = time start execution math calculate until time finish execution

Comment: Then your code is working perfectly

Comment: @Idle_Mind can u help to rewrite my code / fix it using tick ? , i'm beginner /

Comment: @Plutonix yes working but the results have a tendency to increase ?
I want to like, if the result is 100ms, then the result is not more than a span of 150 ms or less than 50 ms

Comment: Thats not true.  The results in the picture are Down, Up, Up, Down, Up, Down, Up  the score is 4 to 3

Comment: @Plutonix how to more stable result in range ?

Comment: The stopwatch measures the time between the call to `Start()` and the call to `Stop()`. There is no guarantee that the code will always take the same time to execute, there are many things that may effect the time the code needs to execute, like the available memory, the available cpu, etc.